Continuity of monomial
I want to show formally that a simple monomial $p : \mathbb{R}^n \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ where $p(x) = x_1\cdots x_n$ is continuous. It should be an easy problem but I can't figure out where to go from here. Maybe we can iterate on the first term somehow:
Let $x \in \mathbb{R}^n$; we want to show $p$ is continuous at $x$. That is, wts $\forall \epsilon > 0$, $\exists \delta$ such that,
$$\|x - y\| < \delta \implies \|p(x) - p(y)\| < \epsilon$$
We have
\begin{align*}
    \|p(x) - p(y)\| &= |x_1\cdots x_n - y_1\cdots y_n|\\
    &= |\sum_{i = 0}^{n-1} x_{1}\cdots x_{i + 1}y_{i + 2}\cdots y_n - x_1\cdots x_{i}y_{i + 1}\cdots y_n|\\
    &\leq \sum_{i = 0}^{n-1}|x_{1}\cdots x_{i + 1}y_{i + 2}\cdots y_n - x_1\cdots x_{i}y_{i + 1}\cdots y_n|\\
    &= \sum_{i = 0}^{n-1}|(x_1 \cdots x_iy_{i + 2}\cdots y_n)(x_{i + 1} - y_{i + 1})|\\
    &\leq \sum_{i = 0}^{n-1}|x_1 \cdots x_iy_{i + 2}\cdots y_n|\cdot|x_{i + 1} - y_{i + 1}|\\
\end{align*}

Have you tried using induction?

Put an upper bound on $\delta$, e.g. $\delta \le 1$. You can then see that $|x - y| \le \delta \implies |x_i - y_i| \le 1$, so $|y_i| \le 1 + |x_i|$. This can help you bound your first term by a product in terms of the $|x_i|$s.

One way is to use induction on $n$. Another is to see that $f = (f_1,\ldots,f_n)$ is continuous iff each $f_i$ is continuous. If you want to use your method, Theo's idea will be useful.
